# Problems with English and Persian baseline alignment

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, arabic, baseline, persian

I have a document in English and Persian, and the Latin and Persian scripts don't quite line up along the baseline. I am using `polyglossia`, but `xepersian` didn't help me either.

In the MWE below, I have added `fbox` to help illustrate the problem. The periods (full stops) are somehow on the same baseline, but the Persian text is raised up a little bit. How can I bring the Persian text down to the same baseline as the English? Keep in mind I have a document full of both scripts (including tables), so the solution needs to work universally.

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{farsi}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}
    \newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic]{Arial} % Times New Roman didn't make a difference

\begin{document}

Sara has long hair. \textfarsi{سارا موی بلندی دارد.}

\fbox{Sara has long hair.} \fbox{\textfarsi{سارا موی بلندی دارد.}}
\fbox{Sara has long hair. \textfarsi{سارا موی بلندی دارد.}}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: That is a font issue. The Arabic glyphs in Arial are raised above the base line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Amiri](https://www.amirifont.org/) font gives better results:

[image]

Comment: That does indeed do a better job, though that font isn't my favorite. I'll have to play around with more fonts apparently, because I tried a bunch and none gave me results like Amiri.